# Is there a topological way to see that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ have equal cardinality?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I know the "interleaving" proof sending the tuple $(0.x_1x_2\dots,0.y_1y_2\dots)\mapsto0.x_1y_1x_2y_2\dots$, showing $(0,1)\cong(0,1)^2$, which can be extended to $\mathbb R\cong\mathbb R^2$. But this relies on a particular representation of real numbers, and the bijection behaves quite poorly from a topological point of view.

Since the reals are at their heart a topological construction (the completion of the rationals), as well as $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ both having very clear geometric (and thus topological) interpretations, I wonder wether we can see $\mathbb R\cong\mathbb R^2$ due to topological reasons.

Alternatively, I can imagine that the fact that $X\cong X^2$ is a more general fact which does not depend on topological facts about the reals in the first place. Can we show that every infinite set $X$ (infinite in whatever sense you want, as long as the reals are covered by it) satisfies $X\cong X^2$?

Comment: Interestingly, the statement "$X\equiv X^2$ for every infinite set $X$" (where "$\equiv$" means "has the same cardinality as") is **equivalent to** the axiom of choice! This was proved by Zermelo, if I recall correctly.

Comment: More to the point of your question, there are continuous surjections $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (trivial) and $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ (Peano), so by Schroeder-Bernstein + the axiom of choice we get a bijection between the two. But this is *harder* than the purely set-theoretic argument, and the relation "continuously surjects onto" isn't that important in topology. (A quotient map is more than just a continuous surjection.)

Comment: Despite the existence of continuous surjections both ways, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are quite different from a topological point of view.  In particular they are very far from being homeomorphic as topological spaces.  Perhaps this is the reason bijections totally ignore the topology.  On the other hand, as measurable spaces, equipped with their respective Borel $\sigma $-algebras, they are isomorphic in the sense that there is a bijection preserving Borel sets.  This follows from Kuratowski's Theorem.

Comment: Since the Cantor set $C$ is *homeomorphic* to $C^2$, and the set $P$ of irrational numbers is homeomorphic to $P^2$, your question reduces to showing "topologically" that $|\mathbb R|=|P|$ or that $|\mathbb R|=|C|$.

Comment: It's easy to define a strictly increasing function $f:[0,1]\to C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set. Namely, define $f(x)=\min\{y\in C:\mu([0,y]\cap C)=x\}$ where $\mu$ is the natural probability measure on $C$. With the Cantor–Bernstein theorem this shows that $|\mathbb R|=|C|$ whence $|\mathbb R^2|=|C^2|=|C|=|\mathbb R|$.

Comment: There are some *really* weird topological spaces having the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$ (well, weird from the point of, say, a first semester topology student). The comments of @bof point out some of them, and let me throw in $C[0,1]=$ the space of continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$. I'm sure that we have not plumbed the depths of the collection of topological spaces having the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are continuous surjections in either direction between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ and of course $\mathbb{R}$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace. On the other hand there is no continuous *injection* $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, the image has to be an interval, and removing a point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that maps to an interior point of this interval leaves the domain connected but disconnects the image. This restricts what forms of *topological proof* of the bijection are possible.

Here is a generalization of the interleaving argument: since $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N}$, for a set of the form $X = Y^\mathbb{N}$ we have $X \cong X^2$. This gives us the fact about $\mathbb{R}$ after deciding on a bijection $\mathbb{R} \cong \{0, \dotsc, 9\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. You could also replace $\mathbb{N}$ with other infinite sets, though the usual bijection $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N}$ is particularly easy to write down explicitly.

As mentioned in the comments again, you need to use some choice to show for general infinite sets $X$ that $X \cong X^2$.